# How to make visible Bluetooth connection on a laptop with Windows 8.1?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, windows-8.1, bluetooth

I have a Toshiba laptop, with Windows 8.1 installed on it and I want to transfer a file from my smart phone (Samsung Galaxy Gio) to the aforementioned laptop.

The problem is that, although I opened the Bluetooth adapter, on the laptop, I can't seem to make it visible to the phone. I tinkered into the Control Panel and all that I found was the on/off switch. Once I turned it on, the laptop also looks for devices, but it doesn't find any, although the phone's Bluetooth is on and visibile.

I am sure that the phone is not the problem because I had successfully sent files from it to another laptop using Bluetooth.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried this? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/add-a-bluetooth-enabled-device-to-your-computer

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it wasn't the cause. Meanwhile, I found the cause of the problem. The question can be closed.

Comment: ok, just answer your own question so other people know how to fix it if they get the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the laptop had two different Bluetooth driver versions for the same device. The second driver was installed without my knowledge. Uninstalling the last driver installed solved the problem.